# EXPO How to stop audio in REACT-MATIVE after some time?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

today I wanted to experiment with the audio in the React-native. I want to start my sound and then stop it after 5 sec so i follow instructions in expo website for audio (expo-av) so my code so far looks like that -

```
  const [sound, setSound] = React.useState();

  async function playSound() {
    console.log("Loading Sound");
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
      require("./assets/sound.mp3")
    );
    setSound(sound);

    console.log("Playing Sound");
    await sound.playAsync();
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log("Unloading Sound");
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]); 

.
.
.
      <Button
        title={"Play"}
        onPress={async () => {
          await playSound();

          setTimeout(async () => {
            await sound.stopAsync();
          }, 5000);
        }}
      />
```

but i got error

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating 'sound.stopAsync')]

Why? I can`t understad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the sound when you mount the component the error goes away. Otherwise you have to press the button twice to get some result. Here's [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/hOma2bN9v)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

export default function App() {
  const [sound, setSound] = React.useState();
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = React.useState(false)
  async function loadSound(){
    console.log('Loading Sound');
      const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
        require('./assets/sound.mp3')
      );
      setSound(sound);
  }
  async function playSound() {
    if (!sound) {
      await loadSound()
    }
    console.log(await sound.getStatusAsync());
    if(!isPlaying){

    console.log('Playing Sound');
    await sound.playAsync();
    }
    else{
      await sound.stopAsync();
    }
    setIsPlaying(prev=>!prev)
  }
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    loadSound()
  },[])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return sound
      ? () => {
          console.log('Unloading Sound');
          sound.unloadAsync();
        }
      : undefined;
  }, [sound]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title={isPlaying ? 'Stop' :"Start"} onPress={playSound} />
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```